# Nestje subscription getting NULL and with the error: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription"

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

This is a simple test for Subscription in my nestjs project with graphql, but I got the error: `Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription`

Here is the code:

```js
  //* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Subscription ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
  @Mutation((returns) => Boolean)
  testSubscription() {
    pubsub.publish('somethingOnTrack', {
      somethingOnTrack: 'something',
    });
    return true;
  }
  @Subscription((returns) => String)
  orderSubscription() {
    return pubsub.asyncIterator('somethingOnTrack');
  }
```

Just create a subscription and test it.

Here is the GraphQLModule in the `app.module` in nestjs:

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  autoSchemaFile: true,
  subscriptions: {
    'graphql-ws': true,
    'subscriptions-transport-ws': true,
  },
}),
```

it try to using `graphql-ws` & `subscriptions-transport-ws`

**Next**, I test it in the graphql:

```js
subscription {
  orderSubscription
}
```

```js
mutation {
  testSubscription
}
```

The Mutation can get result as expected:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "testSubscription": true
  }
}
```

But the Subscription got the error:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.orderSubscription.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "orderSubscription"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Seems the subscription cannot get the payload from the pubsub.publish?
**Why** I got this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cz this is code first, just return the type String in Subscription seems not make any sense,
Finally, add a output type dto:

```js
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class SubscriptionOutput {
  @Field((type) => String)
  somethingOnTrack: string;
}
```

***And*** also add {resolve: ...} to the Subscription, seems it is the correct syntax?? Change the test Subscription to follow:

```js
  //* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Subscription ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
  @Mutation((returns) => Boolean)
  testSubscription() {
    this.pubsub.publish('somethingOnTrack', { somethingOnTrack: 'something' });
    return true;
  }
  @Subscription((returns) => SubscriptionOutput, {
    resolve: (payload) => payload,
  })
  orderSubscription() {
    return this.pubsub.asyncIterator('somethingOnTrack');
  }
```